# Count how many errors in the system log?

Tags: powershell

I'd like to count how many errors the are the system event log of a remote server(s)
Is there a way of scripting this using Powershell or something similar to count how many errors have occurred and then save it in a file?

Comment: Do you want to save the error list, or just its count, to file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To list all `Error` types from the `System` log on `someremotehost`:

```
Get-EventLog -LogName System -EntryType Error -ComputerName someremotehost
```

To count them:

```
Get-EventLog -LogName System -EntryType Error -ComputerName someremotehost | Measure-Object
```